Newbie to using Postman with issues
I am trying to setup Postman to access my health data and I am getting constant errors. I am filling out the url and the callback, auth and access token urls. I get error codes everytime. I am either not configuring it correctly, or else the script is corrupted. It just won’t authenticate.
Any help in setting this up greatly appreciated
Everything I tried is already mentioned in the post.
I am using version 11.11
